# PHP code causing browser to slow down: uploading and displaying a CSV file

Tags: php, html

Which part in this code is causing the whole system to lag? I am trying to upload a .csv file and display it on the same page. Moreover, is there a way to let users browse only .csv files using the only HTML when I have an input type of "file"? `accept=".csv"` not working!

```
<?php
//code
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)) {
  $csvfile=$target_file;
  $successful="The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
//html  
  echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
  $f = fopen("$csvfile", "r");
  while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
      echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
  echo "</tr>\n";
  }
}  
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: I suspect the problem lies within your loop. How large is the file you're uploading? With regards to your second question, the solution is rather simple: `<input type="file" accept=".csv" />`

Comment: Depending on how big the file is, it will take time. You first got the time for the file upload (which is affected by the file size and the users connection speed) and then the iteration (which is affected by the amount of rows and columns). If there are many rows and cells, outputting it all to the browser also takes time.

Comment: html tags are missing (closing body, table). 
fclose() is in wrong place. 
$target_file is not defined. 
Activate error reporting to fix any potential errors/warnings. 
Based on your php version you must (or not) define the second parameter of the fgetcsv() function. Check the php manual for more info.
And make sure you upload a well formatted csv file